# How to permanently disable audio enhancement in windows 10?

Tags: windows, audio, skype

When using Skype, the volume lowers down after a second. I found out that unchecking "audio enhancement" (see picture) solved the problem, but only for a while. When my PC enters into sleep mode or is rebooted, the issue comes back, even though the setting still appear unticked.

I have to tick it again and press "apply" and untick and "apply", and so on, (I am not sure what I do exactly) to finally get the volume to be loud again constantly.

Is there a way to **permanently** get rid of this audio enhancement feature?
Thanks for your insights.

[image: audio enhancement setting]

Comment: See if this helps>>>>https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-audio-enhancements-windows-10

Comment: @Moab Thanks but it does not work, it's the same thing I've already done